# Dichotomizing continuous variables for an EXPERIMENT not a survey

Tags: experiment-design, binning

I've aware of the many issues/pitfalls with splitting continuous variables in survey research. Nothing I have read addresses whether doing so to create groups which will then be assigned to tx conditions in a field experiment is ok, or less bad. (or worse?)

For example:  Social Dominance and Justice System reform. I want to assess the effectiveness of two anti racism workshop styles for persuading people. One uses a colorblind (CB) type message (e.g. we are all the same), the other uses a valuing diversity (VD) (e.g.: we are different and that is good) style message. I have reason to think these messages will have different impacts depending on participants' social dominance orientation.

So I want to split SDO scores into HI-LOW (1 SD above and below the mean on a prescreen) and assign half of each group to each treatment condition CB or VD, for a 2x2 design. I'm predicting support for justice system reform measures.

I'd love to get some input on this question. Citations would be especially helpful.

Clarification: Ss were drawn from a large prescreening session and I needed SDO homogenous groups for the workshops. There is reason to think that SDO homogenous (ish) groups may matter for the workshops to work as intended.

Comment: (1) How are people who are within 1 SD of the mean assigned? They don't belong to either the HI or LOW groups. (2) What advantages do you see for this approach compared to randomly assigning subjects to the two treatments?

Comment: Sorry they were simply not recruited. Please see my clarification above.

Comment: Ah, that explains the 1 SD bit.  But I'm still curious about my second question concerning the alternative of random assignment, because (a) it's a standard approach and (b) by avoiding the binning issue altogether it is likely to make a more powerful study.

Comment: Because there is reason to think that SDO homogenous (ish) groups matter for the workshops to work as intended. @whuber

Answer (score 2):

It still seems like you're throwing a lot of data away and not getting anything in return.

In addition to losing information about each subject's individual SDO score, you're going to end up rejecting a *lot* of subjects  if you only enroll subjects that are at least 1 SD from the mean: around 68 percent, if SDO is normally distributed, potentially more if the scores have heavy tails.

Your analysis strategy would not change. There are still two factors: workshop type, coded as an indicator variable, and initial SDO score. Your hypothesis remains the same: "there is an interaction between the factors", but you may end up with a bit more power to detect an effect.

The results are also easier to visualize: draw a scatter plot of Support vs. SDO Score and color each point according to the workshop type.

I might *grudgingly* consider binning the SDO scores if I wanted the results to be accessible to others who use the same thresholds--perhaps there's a short form of the SDO questionnaire that only spits out LOW, TYPICAL, or HIGH. Even if this were so, I'd suggest just indicating them on the graph instead.

Comment: I hear you but please see my clarifications above @Matt Krause, I recruited from a large prescreen sample so wasting subjects was not really an issue. Also I used the binning to assign Ss to Tx conditions in SDO homogenous groups. Would you recommend I still unbin them for analyses? If so please explain why.

Comment: The prescreen certainly helps, but I still think you're (probably) giving up statistical power. If you're getting something in return for it--the experiment somehow becomes simpler or the results map onto categories that are already used--then it *might* be worth it but I'm not convinced....